# A Maximization Problem involving Fourier Coefficient Constraint

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f$ be a probability density function defined over the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$. For notational simplicity, we represent the  inner product $\langle f\mid g\rangle=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x) g(x) dx$. Given that
$$
|\langle f\mid \cos(2\pi k x)\rangle|\leq \langle f\mid \cos(2\pi x) \rangle\triangleq \alpha_0,\quad \forall k=2,3,\ldots,
$$
 what is the maximum value of $\langle\ln f(x)\mid \cos(2\pi x) \rangle $ in terms of $\alpha_0$?

Thanks,

Mustafa

Comment: There is no trivial relation between the Fourier series of $f$ and the Fourier series of $\log f$: for instance, it is quite hard to check that $f\geq 0$ by the Fourier series of $f$.

Comment: I can see that for an unconstrained setting. I was wondering if, there happens to be a relationship for our setup. Namely, the maximum of the Fourier coefficients of $f$ is bounded and $f$ belongs to the class of density functions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence of probability density functions supported on $I=\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ given by:
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\,\cos(\pi x)^{2n}=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\,\cos(\pi x)^{2n}.\tag{1} $$
We have:
$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f_n(x)\cos(2\pi x)\,dx = \frac{n}{n+1}\tag{2} $$
but since:
$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\log(\cos(\pi x))\cos(2\pi x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\tag{3} $$
we have:
$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\log(f_n(x))\cos(2\pi x)\,dx = \log\left(\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\right)+n \tag{4}$$
so: 
$$\alpha_0\xrightarrow[\scriptstyle{n\to +\infty}]{}1\quad\text{but}\quad \langle \log f_n(x)\mid \cos(2\pi x)\rangle\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{}+\infty\tag{5}$$
gives that there is no way of bounding the second quantity depending just on the first one.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, or maybe I had to be more specific on the nature of $\alpha_0$, which is strictly less than 1 and fixed. I will go over your reasoning and  thanks in advance @jack-daurizio ..

Comment: @Mkesal: let we call "entropy" the quantity $\langle \log f(x)\mid\cos(2\pi x)\rangle$. Here I proved that there is a family of densities with $\alpha_0$ being close to one with an unbounded entropy. With minor adjustements, you can prove that there is a family of densities with the same $\alpha_0$ and unbounded entropy, so there is no way to bound the entropy with a function of $\alpha_0$ only.

Comment: @jack-daurizio I am just curious if this unboundedness is due to the impulsive nature of the density that the sequence converges to. As far as I can say, the dirac delta function has spectra equal to 1 for all modes and I agree that the "entropy" is unbounded for this case. I have to think a bit more on your arguments, and again, thanks for the insight.

Comment: @jack-daurizio I have a quick question. Say we use C-S Inequality, for which the equality is attained by $\ln f(x)=\lambda_1 \cos(2\pi x)+\lambda_0$, where the constants should be chosen to satisfy the normalization and spectral constraint on $f$. It is a simple task to show $f(x)=\frac{1}{I_0(\beta_0)}e^{\beta_0 \cos(2\pi x)}$ is the density that we seek with $\alpha_0=\frac{I_1(\beta_0)}{I_0(\beta_0)}$. Here the functions $I_0$ and $I_1$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first kind. I am sure it is not a valid argument, but just curious if there is any chance to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @Mkesal: it is another way of proving that the entropy cannot be bounded in terms of $\alpha_0$ only, yes. The ratio $r(x)=\frac{I_1(x)}{I_0(x)}$ has a nice continued fraction representation, and it is easy to see that $r$ maps $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $(0,1)$ injectively.

Comment: @jack-daurizio But, if it is a valid argument, then the inner product we seek is simply $\beta_0/2$, and there exists a monotone non-decreasing bijection between $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$, i.e., the inverse of $r(x)$. So, is it not the answer we seek $r^{-1}(\alpha_0)/2$?, which is a function of $\alpha_0$ only? I am a bit confused, you see..

Comment: @Mkesal: you have just proved that for any entropy there is a density with such entropy and with $\alpha_0$ being an arbitrary number in $(0,1)$, so the entropy cannot be bounded in terms of $\alpha_0$, again.

Comment: @jack-daurizio So, you essentially conclude, if $f(x)=1+\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{2}+g(x)$, where $\varphi_k\triangleq \langle g(x)\mid \cos(2\pi k x)\rangle$ satisfies $\varphi_1$=0 and $|\varphi_k|<1/2$, then there exists $g(x)$ such that $\langle \ln f(x)\mid \cos(2\pi x)\rangle\to \infty$. This is the setup for $\alpha_0=1/2$. But then, as $\alpha_0\to 0$, the density converges to uniform, which essentially has entropy $0$. So, there seems to be some kind of discontinuity which is somehow counter-intuitive. Thanks.